# jQuery call error on Page_Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, registerclientscriptblock

I have the following code to register a javascript function on Page_Load (also tried it on Page_Init). The javascript switches two panels from hidden to shown based on a parameter on load of page:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String switchAction = "<script language='javascript'>switchactionpanel(" + (int)((Global.upAction)Enum.Parse(typeof(Global.upAction), Global.ProfileAction.ToString())) + ")</script>";
        Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock("switchaction", switchAction);
    }
```

But when the page loads I am receiving an error: $ is not defined.

I looked in Firebug and the jQuery files are being loaded however, the first file that is being loaded in the .Net tab is the page itself. I know the jquery is correct as the same code works on a different page. Where should my RegisterClientScriptBlock be put in the page lifecycle to work correctly when the page loads? Or am I going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to ensure that the inserted script gets inserted after the JQuery reference.

Use `RegisterStartupScript` instead -- that inserts the script tag before `</form>` closing tag.

Comment: Thank you very much, worked perfectly. So just to get this straight, if I want to run a javascript after the page loads use the StartupScript instead correct? this change has nothing to do with my code specifically right?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is relevant but I always use:
`<script type="text/javascript"...`

Sorry this should have been a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: even though that was missing, still did not correct the problem. After the error is thrown in Firebug and the page loads, I can go into the Firebug console and then $ works fine

Comment: I see. I assume then that when you view source, this script is being called before the jQuery file. You will have to reorganize those so that the jQuery script is called first in order to define `$`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with the register function your using. Try using `RegisterStartupScript` instead of `RegisterClientScriptBlock`.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "switchaction", "<script language='javascript'>switchactionpanel(" + (int)((Global.upAction)Enum.Parse(typeof(Global.upAction), Global.ProfileAction.ToString())) + ")</script>", false);
```

Comment: thank you Steven, dbaseman beat you to it though, but thanks again